# Limit under the integral sign and partition of unity

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set and let $\{ U_j \}_{j=1}^\infty$ be an open covering of $U$ such that $U = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty U_j$.

Suppose $\{ \psi_j \}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a partition of unity subordinate to $\{ U_j \}_{j=1}^\infty$.

Let $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ and let $h \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be such that $\mathrm{supp} \, h \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

In $U$ we have $h = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \psi_j h$ — since $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \psi_j = 1$ in $U$.

I want to prove the following identity (if it holds):
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{U} \vert \nabla u \vert^{p-2}\nabla u \cdot \nabla \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \psi_j h \right) = \int_{U} \vert \nabla u \vert^{p-2}\nabla u \cdot \nabla h.$$

I failed using the dominated convergence theorem: the main difficulty is to find $g \in L^1(U)$ such that — almost everywhere on $U$ and for every $n$ — there holds
$$\vert \nabla u \vert^{p-1} \bigg\lvert \sum_{j=1}^n \nabla (\psi_j h) \bigg\rvert \leq g.$$

I'm not sure the above identity is valid; what I'm trying to do is replace $h$ whose support is not necessary entirely in $U$ by a function $\widetilde{h} \in C_c^\infty(U)$ such that, assuming $u = 0$ outside $U$, we have
$$\int_{\mathrm{supp} \, h \cap U} \vert \nabla u \vert^{p-2}\nabla u \cdot \nabla h = \int_U \vert \nabla u \vert^{p-2}\nabla u \cdot \nabla \widetilde{h}.$$

Comment: $\{U_j\}_j$ is a locally finite covering?

Comment: We may assume it is. But since $\overline{U}$ is compact, any open covering of $U$ can be refined to a locally finite covering. Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe its is not true for every partition of unity, however, I think it is possible to construct a open covering of $U$, and a partition of unity subordinate to it, where the above is true.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $d(x,y) = \vert y - x \vert$ is a metric space, hence paracompact. Thus every open cover of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^N$ has an open refinement that is locally finite. Anyway, by Theorem 3.15 in Adams' book (Sobolev Spaces), there exists a partition of unity subordinate to any open covering of any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. The main difficulty here is the passage of the limit under the integral sign.

Comment: Sorry, I think you have misunderstood my comment. What I said in the last comment, has to be applied to your convergence. I think that the convergence will depend on the open convering.

Comment: Ok! Since the open covering is locally finite, for every $n$ and for almost every $x \in U$, there exists a constant $C_x > 0$ such that: $\lvert \nabla u(x) \rvert^{p-1} \bigg\lvert \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \nabla ( (\psi_j h)(x) ) \bigg\rvert \leq C_x \lvert \nabla u (x) \rvert^{p-1}$. We could define $g(x) = C_x \lvert \nabla u(x) \rvert^{p-1}$, but there is no guarantees that $g \in L^1(U)$.

Comment: If you cover $U$ with a finite number of set then, $C_x$ is bounded.

Comment: Actually, $U = \mathrm{supp} \, h \cap \Omega \neq \emptyset$ for some open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$. $\overline{U}$ is compact but it can't be covered by open sets of $\Omega$. Can $U$ be covered by a finite number of open sets belonging to $\Omega$ ? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can certainly cover it with a finite number of open set, because $\partial U$ is compact, however, is this useful for you somehow? I mean, it seems from your question that you want make the functions supported in $U$. With a finite cover, this is not possible.

Comment: I want to replace $h_{\lvert U}$ by a function $\widetilde{h} \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\int_U \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{p-2} \nabla u \cdot \nabla h = \int_U \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{p-2} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \widetilde{h}$. If there exists a finite open covering of $U$ by open sets in $\Omega$, with partition of unity $\{ \psi_j \}$, then $h_{\lvert U} = \sum_{j=1}^n \psi_j h_{\lvert U}$ and we are done because $\psi_j h \in C_c^\infty(U_j)$. But the fact that $\partial \Omega \cap \partial U \neq \emptyset$ seems to prevent the finite open covering to exist.

Comment: Let $\{ W_j \}$ be an open cover of $\overline{U}$ by open sets $W_j \subset \mathbb{R}^N$. Since $\overline{U}$ is compact, we can extract a finite open cover of $\overline{U}$ which we denote by $\{ \widetilde{W}_j \}$. Then $\{ U_j \} = \{ \widetilde{W}_j \cap \Omega \}$ is a finite open cover of $U$ by open sets in $\Omega$. Is this valid?